# Generated a percentage based (not counted based) frequency table in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregation

I would like to make a frequency table that is percent based with a single SQL statement. So if I have a table of men and women like this:

```
Name    Gender   
Allen    M
Jerry    M
Marsha   F
Alice    F
```

I'd like to end with this table:

```
Gender   Freq
M        .50
F        .50
```

I know I can count and group, but how can I divide the counts by group by the total count of the table?

Answer (score 1):

Most SQL dialects support the ANSI standard window functions.  Using them you can do:

```
select gender, count(*), count(*) / sum(count(*) * 1.0) over ()
from t
group by gender;
```

The `* 1.0` is simply because some databases do integer division of integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query

```
SELECT gender,cast(count(1) OVER(Partition by GENDER order by GENDER)/(count(1) OVER( order by (select 1))*1.0) as numeric(4,2)) freq
FROM #temp
GROUP BY gender
ORDER BY Gender desc
```